# How to find files inside a folder when war file is deployed on server?

Tags: java, file, wildfly

I am able to read specific files using **getResourceAsStream()** function. I have tried using the same input stream for fetching file names but that did not work. This is the code that i used for that

```
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)));

String line;

while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
  LOG.info("Testing File: " + line);
}
rdr.close();
```

**More info :** zip file is deployed on wildfly server

Tried fetching whole path with this but it gives wrong location 
`this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`

Comment: And what error does the above code give?

Comment: There is no error as such, ```rdr.readLine()``` returns null so did not work out for me.

Comment: I would guess you're getting an empty file then.

Comment: That folder exist, I am able to fetch files inside it by using ```getResourceAsStream()``` as mentioned in question.

Comment: You can't iterate files like that. If you have a set of files you need to iterate those need to be in a real directory not the deployment.